# 'Controller as' syntax function not firing

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to convert my controller '$scope syntax' to 'controller as' syntax and for some reason my function stopped firing and can't figure out whats going on.

The clearCheck() is one example, but none of my functions are working.

```
 <div ng-controller="tipController as vm">
  <div class="row checkTotalDisplay selected">
    <div class="col totalDisplayTitle">Check Total</div>
    <div class="col col-50 totalDisplayAmt">${{vm.checkTotal}} <i class="ion-close-circled" ng-click="vm.clearCheck()"></i></div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

---

```
.controller('tipController', ["$scope", function ($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  var DEFAULT_CHECK_TOTAL = '0.00'; // display correctly shows 0.00

  $scope.vm = {
    checkTotal: DEFAULT_CHECK_TOTAL
  };

   function clearCheck() {
     vm.clearCheck = clearCheck; // doesn't fire
     console.log(vm.checkTotal); // doesn't fire
     vm.checkTotal = '4'; // doesn't fire
   };
}]);
```

---

$scope syntax which works:

```
.controller('tipController', function($scope) {

  $scope.checkTotal = '0.00';

  $scope.clearCheck = function () {
     $scope.checkTotal = '4'; // correctly changes display to '4'
  };
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be misunderstanding a bit about `vm` in this context.  Effectively, you're going to do the same thing in your original controller with `$scope` except you replace `$scope` with `vm`.

```
.controller('tipController', function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.checkTotal = '0.00';

  vm.clearCheck = function () {
     vm.checkTotal = '4'; // correctly changes display to '4'
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your controller, you declare

```
$scope.vm = {
    checkTotal: DEFAULT_CHECK_TOTAL
};
```

You then do a `tipController as vm`

When you're binding `{{vm.checkTotal}}` vm is NOT $scope.vm, it is $scope. For what you've written, you would use `{{vm.vm.checkTotal}}` ($scope.vm.checkTotal).

Edit: [Makoto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1079354/makoto)'s answer shows how you would accomplish the behavior you desire.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, but checkTotal is actually displaying correctly oddly enough. It's when I try to use a function it doesn't work.